# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'moment' in moment-date-adapter.d.ts

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular6

Using Angular 6, I am having trouble with my material-moment-adapter.  In my moment-date-adapter.d.ts file it shows that "'module' cannot be found" on my import statements when trying to import { Moment } from

node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter/typings/adapter/moment-date-adapter.d.ts.

My tsconfig.json is as follows:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ] 
  }
}
```

My import statement is simply

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';
```

from my moment-date-adapter.d.ts file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello Andrew, did you found a solution for your problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Installing @types/moment as a dev dependency solved it for me.

Comment: I wanted to upvote this again after half a year as I completely forgot what's the problem.

Answer (score -3):

try to install Moment.js: 
npm i moment